# GCM on iOS doesn't send data object for content_available notifications

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

When I send a GCM message with the content_available=true flag set, the userInfo dictionary in the didReceiveRemoteNotification: callback is null.

Here's the callback in my UIApplication delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler {
    NSLog(@"Notification: %@", userInfo);
    [[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
}
```

Here's a sample CURL request that works:

```
curl --header 'Authorization: key=…' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "registration_ids": ["…"], "data": { "test": "test test test" }}' https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

I get the expected result:

```
Notification: {"collapse_key" = "do_not_collapse";    from = …;    test = "test test test";\^J}
```

However, when I add the content_available flag so the push can work while the app is in the background:

```
curl --header 'Authorization: key=…' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "registration_ids": ["…"], "data": { "test": "test test test" }, "content_available": true}' https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

NSLog outputs "(null)" for the userInfo object.  Has anyone else run into this issue and have a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was just a problem with iOS 9 beta 3, it works correctly on iOS 8.4.